# How to implement didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method when the app is launched as a result of location change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, location, core-location

I'm using Region Monitoring in my app and it's work pretty well when I'm walking around the city with an app launched.

The problem I have is receiving those location changes notifications when my app is terminated. My app is crashing when it's waken up because of location change and it crashes when I'm trying to set rootViewController in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.

1. Should I implement this method differently when my app is launched in the background as a result of location change?
2. How much time do I have in the background to perform my tasks when my app is waken up when entering/exciting region?

Comment: You can't launch your app from the background- the user launches it. If your app is terminated, you won't receive any messages from iOS- perhaps you've meant backgrounded? Also, please provide a snippet of code to show us more clearly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yup, I was thinking about the situation when the app is in the background and is killed by the system (e.g. because iOS had to free memory for other apps). Then, it's relaunched in the background when user changes his location.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, iOS / Apple says you have about 10 seconds to do the necessary.

First question:

In your app delegate.h, add: `CLLocationManagerDelegate`

In your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method add:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
```

And also add:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    [notification setSoundName:UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName];
    [notification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];

    if(state == CLRegionStateInside) {
        [notification setAlertBody:@"CLRegionStateInside"];
    }
    else if(state == CLRegionStateOutside) {
        [notification setAlertBody:@"CLRegionStateOutside"];
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}
```

Then, where you have your region code (Probably somewhere in some view controller), add: `[yourRegion setNotifyEntryStateOnDisplay:YES];`

before your original call to:

`[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:yourRegion];`

That's all!